# SQL "IN subquery" when subquery can be NULL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql, arel

I have a query that needs to return results that are NOT matched in a sub query.  The sub query can return an empty result, so I need to set a  default value (say 0) if the sub query returns an empty set to prevent `IN (NULL)` which always returns another NULL.

For example

```
SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE id NOT IN (subquery_that_selects_ids)
```

`subquery_that_selects_ids` can return a set of integers, i.e. (1,2,5,6)
or an empty set if subquery finds no matching results.

`COALESCE` doesn't work here, since the sub query will likely return more than one result.

Solutions need to work in SQLite or postgresql.
How can I prevent the sub query from returning an empty set?

---

Everyone is telling me that the query should work as written.  And you are all correct.  The query is being built by Rails3's AREL, as I was about to post the full query here I noticed that AREL was putting NULL in for an empty set when using array conditions.

I.E.  My query in rails looked like:

```
Object.where("id NOT IN (?)", Object.where(other_conditions).select(:id))
```

when `Object.where(other_conditions)` evaluated to `[]` the `?` was being replaced with `NULL`

So I re-write the query to look like:

```
Object.where("id NOT IN (" + Object.where(other_conditions).select(:id).to_sql + ")")
```

Problem solved.

I'm giving credit to @Michael Buen, but also upvoting anyone who told me the query would work as written, since they are correct.  Thanks to @OMG Ponies and @Ted Elliott especially!

Comment: Can you post some sample data, and a real subquery?  It's not clear to me how NULL would be returned from a subquery unless you are specifying criteria for it.

Comment: The subquery should return no records, not NULL, shouldn't it?  Eaither way whether the sub query returns NULL or no records the "id IN (subquery_that_selects_ids)" clause is going to be NULL or false either way which would result in the main query returning no records.  Is that not the desired result?

Comment: your right, not NULL, but an empty set [], which seems is being treated as NULL when NOT IN is evaluated

Comment: Ted Elliott, when the subquery returns a empty set, the desired result is that the main query return ALL of it's results

Comment: If it's an empty set, clearly the `example_table.id` values compared are not in it.  Either it's a misunderstanding on your part, or you'll have to provide some manner of details to demonstrate your issue in order to get useful help.

Comment: Thanks for dialoging with me.  Maybe I am misunderstanding... My thought was that, as you said 'clearly the values are not in it', so therefore, any values selected by the main query would be returned, as they are NOT IN (empty_set).

Comment: I think you are complicating it a bit, NOT IN will have rows even there's no rows in subquery. Your query will work without modification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM example_table 
WHERE id NOT 
    IN (select x.id from subquery_that_selects_ids as x where x.id is not null)
```

I think you are complicating it a bit, NOT IN will have rows even there's no rows in subquery. Your query will work without modification.  Anyway, if you really desire your subquery to yield row(s) even if the conditions wasn't satisfied, use UNION

```
SELECT * FROM example_table 
WHERE id NOT 
    IN (select x.id from subquery_that_selects_ids as x 
        where 1 = 0 -- empty set
        union
        select 0)
```

UNION eliminates duplicate anyway, UNION ALL preserve duplicates

Comment: The problem is not that I have NULLs in the result of the subquery, but that the entire subquery is an empty set, so select x.id from subquery_that_selects_ids as x where x.id is not null will still return an empty set.

Answer (score 2):

what about:

```
SELECT ex.ID, ex.OtherFields
FROM ExampleTable ex left join (Select ID from SomeOtherTable) o on o.ID = ex.ID
WHERE o.ID is null
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing something.  The query you posted works just fine if `subquery_that_selects_ids` returns an empty set (so every row from `example_table` is selected).  There are no implicit null values involved here.

You may be thinking of the situation where a subquery is used as a scalar.  In that case, the result value is null if the subquery returns no rows, e.g.,

```
SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM other_table WHERE name = 'foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't this work?

```
SELECT *
  FROM example_table
 WHERE id IN (
    SELECT COALESCE(id, 0)
      FROM another_example_table
);
```

Comment: that doesn't work in my case because there is nothing to SELECT, and therefore nothing to COALESCE with

Comment: How can there be "nothing" to select in a subselect?

Answer (score 0):

On multi-valued subquery will have problems if you use the NOT in operator AND if the set returned by the subquery contains a NULL value. If the subquery is an empty set, that doesn't mean that it returned null ;)

In the case of containing a null value, it forces the outer query to return one empty set because it cannot say if the value is in UNKNOWN or NOT IN Unknown.

Here is one example using **hr.employees table**.

*SELECT last_name
FROM hr.employees
WHERE commission_pct NOT IN (0.1,0.35);*

This query will return 26 rows.

*SELECT last_name
FROM hr.employees
WHERE commission_pct NOT IN (0.1,0.35,NULL);*

This query returns no rows because the NULL in the list passed to NOT IN will spoil it out. SO, if your subquery may return any null value, you should treat it with the functions (NVL,NVL2,COALESCE) in the subquery.

Hope this helped.

Thanks

Alexander Bufalo